# Function to convert timeStamp to hours form

Tags: angular

I already built this function that converts time from timeStamp form to hours form but the the result shows the time with one number.... 
e.g. (420 > 7 am) I want to show like (07 am)

```
 convertTime(time: number) {

    let hours: number = Math.floor(time / 60);
    let minutes: number = time % 60;

    if (hours <= 12) return hours + ':' + minutes + ' am';
    else return (hours - 12 ) + ':' + minutes + ' pm';
}
```

Comment: You already know how to concatenate strings, how to use `if`, and how to compare numbers, so concatenatenating 0 if the hour is less than 10 shouldn't be a problem. Should it?

Answer (score 0):

```
convertTime(time: number) {

    let hours: number = Math.floor(time / 60);
    let minutes: number = time % 60;

    if (hours <= 12 && hours >=10) return hours + ':' + minutes + ' am';
    else if(hours < 10) return '0' + hours + ':'+ minutes +' am';

    else return (hours - 12 ) + ':' + minutes + ' pm';
}
```